# Using Chosen.js with Django

Tags: django, multi-select, jquery-chosen

Hello Im trying to implement chosen.js into my Django project and so far it works great. I only have one issue which I cannot solve. I have a model where "language" is a `ChardField`. I wanted to let the User choose more than one language so I tried to use chosen Multiple. Since a Charfield can only hold one Value so I used [Django Multiselect](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield). Now the Chosen.js is not working anymore and I have no idea what to do. 
Models:

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    language = MultiSelectField(verbose_name=_(u"Content Language"), 
     max_length=40, choices=settings.LANGUAGES,default='en')`
```

Forms:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields=[
      'language',
         .....
      ]
```

Template:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% csrf_token %}
<span>Content language {{ form.language|add_class:"chosen-select" }}</span>
```

So the question is how do I get the normal chosen.js input field to a multiple chosen field (with Django)? I know there is the possibility to add a multiple field to the forms but this messes up my hole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented the chosen multi select by the following:

Forms

```
class select_language(ModelForm):
    #Get data for choice boxes
    language_results = language.objects.all()    
    select_language = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=language_results,
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'placeholder': "Choose the users(s)",
        'class': 'chosen-select',
        'multiple tabindex': '4',
    }),
)
```

Template:

```
....
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chosen.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'prism.css' %}">    
....
{{ select_language.select_language }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'chosen.jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'docsupport/prism.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'docsupport/init.js' %}"></script>
```

Of course you will need to update the locations for the static files. Hopefully this is a good starting direction.